# Google Chart (for pivot table) legend labels display wrong

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

In my Google Sheets spreadsheet, I have a pivot table, and a column chart connected to it.

But the legend of the chart is displaying not just the headings, but also the two cells below the headings. For instance, the pivot table looks like this:

```
Date    Labeling   Quality   Weight
1/31       3          5        6
2/7        3          5        1
2/18       8          1        4
2/25       7          2        9
```

And the Legend box of the chart, which designates the columns, looks like this:

```
Labeling 3 3
Quality  5 5
Weight   6 1
```

EDIT: I didn't thing the configuration of the chart was important, since it seems to be working except for the legend. But if it helps: The Date column is the X-axis, the Labeling, Quality, and Weight are the data series (columns).

Comment: How could we possibly help if you do not share the configuration of your chart?

Comment: Is that better? What else do you need?

Comment: Have you made sure that the chart's data source is correct? Right click on the chart -> Data range.

Comment: Confirmed. The Data Range starts in A8 (where the "Date" header is). The Series all start in Row 8 also.